# Events when stateless ejb is assigned to the pool and vice versa

Tags: events, ejb, stateless

is there any events like @PostConstruct and ... when a stateless ejb is assigned to the pool?

I want to reset som local variables when it happens.

RGDS

Comment: which pool? Thread pool or Bean Pool? When the server receives a request it assings a thread from the thread pool and a bean from the bean pool to serve the request. The bean has been in the pool all the time, so it is never assigned to the pool. Do you mean when a bean becomes available again?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such mechanism (at least, nothing spec-mandated, and I'm not aware of any vendor extensions).  If you give more details on what you're trying to do, someone might be able to give alternative advice.

Comment: I want to store some states with local variables inside the stateless bean and I want to reset them when the bean use for new client request

Comment: Then use method local variables, not an instance variables.